# C++ Check user's first name is not too short

Tags: c++, function

I have a function (below) that checks the user's first name for invalid characters and it works fine.

```
    while(run)
{
    size_t positionFirstName = userFirstName.find_first_of(invalidCharacter, 0,      sizeof(invalidCharacter));
    if (positionFirstName != string::npos) 
    {
        cout << "Please only use letters. Please re-enter your first name." << endl;
        cin >> userFirstName;



    }

    else
    {

        run = false;
    }

}
```

I also want to check that the user's first name is not shorter than 3 characters.
I have tried a few times, and can get the program to run the first function, but if I put in  another function to check name length, it seems to skip it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show what you tried?

Comment: Do you know about `size()` or `length()`?

Comment: My name is Ed, nice to meet you.  I wish you had told my mother that my name was invalid 30 years ago, would have saved me some frustration.

Comment: "I have tried a few times" - Can you show it in your code?

Comment: You might want to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) before you start to check the validity of someone's name :)

Comment: It's *amazing*, questioner is having a problem with some code, but instead of showing the code that doesn't work, instead posts some code that does work. Really, I mean really? Oh well looks like they got what they wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly adjusted way to do it:

```
cout << "Please enter your first name." << endl;

while( cin >> userFirstName )
{
    size_t positionFirstName = userFirstName.find_first_of(invalidCharacter, 0, sizeof(invalidCharacter));

    if (positionFirstName != string::npos) 
    {
        cout << "Please only use letters.";
    }
    else if( userFirstName.size() < 3 )
    {
        cout << "Name must be at least 3 characters long."
    }
    else {
        break;
    }

    cout << "  Please re-enter your first name." << endl;
}
```

Note that I've avoided repetition, but printing only the errors and handling the input in one place.